# What rule is being applied to justify this summation equality?

Tags: summation

In computing a sum, my book writes
$$\sum_{7\leq k^2\leq 45} \frac{1}{k} = \sum_{\lceil \sqrt{7} \rceil \leq k \leq \lfloor \sqrt{45}\rfloor} \frac{1}{k}$$
How did they do this? I'm not looking for a proof that the two sums are indeed equal, I'm looking for a general rule that justifies the equality and can be applied to other similar situations.

Comment: It's not true if we allow $k$ to be negative. Regardless, they're simply solving for $k$ in the original series of inequalities, nothing special

Comment: @EeveeTrainer Where did the floors and ceilings come from?

Comment: It is because the series is implicitly iterated over integer valued $k$. @user236343  They are technically not required, but useful as a reminder .

Comment: @GrahamKemp Well there are other integers besides ceil(sqrt(7)) and floor(sqrt(45)). Why did they pick these bounds instead of e.g. ceil(sqrt(7)) and the result of rounding sqrt(45) to the nearest integer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Eevee Trainer [points out in the comments](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4399865/what-rule-is-being-applied-to-justify-this-summation-equality#comment9202691_4399865), this isn't correct in general. In fact, if we allow $k$ to be any integer, the left-hand sum is $0,$ while the right-hand sum is positive. However, I assume that in context, $k$ is known to be non-negative.

As for why they're equivalent if $k\geq 0,$ note that for such integers $k,$ we have that the following are equivalent:

- $7\leq k^2$
- $\sqrt 7\leq k$
- $\left\lceil\sqrt{7}\right\rceil\leq k$

The following are also equivalent to each other for integers $k\geq 0$:

- $k^2\leq 45$
- $k\leq\sqrt 45$
- $k\leq\left\lfloor\sqrt{45}\right\rfloor$